# POST Data not inserting into sql table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am using a form. (I wanted the message text as a text area but changed back to normal text to see if this was the problem)

This is the form I am using

```
<form name="addmessage" method="POST" action="addmessage.php" >
    <input type="text" name="message_title" id="message_title">Message Title</input>
    <input type="text" name="message_text" id="message_text">Message</input>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value = Add> 
  </form>
```

Below is the PHP code. I understand i need to protect against sql injection however, i can do this later.

```
    <?php
include_once("config.php");
if(isset($_POST["message_title"]) && strlen($_POST["message_title"])>0) 
    {
$message_title=$_POST['message_title'];
$message_text=$_POST['message_text'];
session_start();
$barber_id = $_SESSION['barber_id'];

$insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO messages(barber_id,message_title,message_text) VALUES('".$barber_id."','".$message_title."',".$message_text.")");

}
else

{
    //Output error
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Error You have left it blank');
    exit();
}

header("location:messages.php");
?>
```

If manually enter data using phpMyAdmin, I can get it to display using the code below.

```
include_once("config.php");
        session_start();
        $barber_id = $_SESSION['barber_id'];
        $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE barber_id ='$barber_id' ");
            //get all records from  table
            while($row = $results->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $prices_id = $row['prices_id'];
                echo '<div data-role="collapsible">';   
                echo '<h1>';
                echo '   Message Title: ';  
                echo $row['message_title'];
                echo '</a>';
                echo '</h1>';
                echo '<p>';
                echo $row['message_text'];
                echo '<a href="delete_price.php?prices_id='.$prices_id.'"  class="ui-btn ui-icon-delete "> Delete</a></div>';
            }
  $mysqli->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: `$message_text` is not quoted in your SQL string. Besides helping to prevent SQL injection, as you mentioned in your question, another good reason to use prepared statements instead of building SQL this way is that you won't have to worry about this kind of thing.

Comment: Do use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php on your query. It will help you find the errors in your code.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by prepared statements?

Answer (score 0):

At `$insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO messages(barber_id,message_title,message_text) VALUES('".$barber_id."','".$message_title."',".$message_text.")");`

you should write

```
$insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO messages(barber_id,message_title,message_text) VALUES('".$barber_id."','".$message_title."','".$message_text."')");
```

Everytime you pass a String or other non int values you must pass them like that: 'xx', otherwise mysql will see it as query param and it crashes.

Comment: I can see where you made the change, but showing exactly what you did and explaning why, will help the OP including future readers.